# How to add data to mongoDB array?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, push

Below is my code to add reviews to my reviews array in the restaurant object

```
async created (restaurantId, title, reviewer, rating, dateOfReview, review) {
    
    const restaurantsCollection = await restaurants();
    let newReview = {
      restaurantId : restaurantId,
      title : title,
      reviewer : reviewer,
      rating : rating,
      dateOfReview : dateOfReview,
      review : review
    };

    const restaurant = await restaurantsCollection.findOne({ _id: restaurantId });
    restaurant.reviews.push(newReview);

}
```

This does not add any data to the DB, what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understand right, you need to call the update after pushing that to your reviews.

```
await restaurantsCollection.updateOne({restaurantId : newReview.restaurantId},{ $set: {reviews: restaurant.reviews} }
```

or you can easily push it like this and no need to do the findOne query:

```
 await restaurantsCollection.updateOne({restaurantId : newReview.restaurantId},{ $push: {reviews: newReview.review} }
```

Comment: thank you, I  didn't know about the $push

Answer (score 1):

**Don't forget to save the review after pushing it to the array.**

```
await restaurant.save()
```